# How Do I Use Dynamic SQL (MySQL) To Store The Result of a Query Into a Local Variable?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

In the procedure I'm writing I need to store the result of a dynamic SQL query into a local variable. Something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_maxsum(uid varchar(25))
BEGIN

    DECLARE maxsum int;
    SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(sum_val) FROM ', uid);
            PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
            EXECUTE stmt INTO maxsum;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    SELECT maxsum;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local variables cannot be assigned in prepared statements. You can use user-defined variables though:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_maxsum(uid varchar(25))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(sum_val) INTO @maxsum FROM ', uid);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SELECT @maxsum;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That does exactly what I need it to!